# C# Lambda Conversion to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda

Hi I have been looking at certain tutorials on sharparchitecture and trying to no avail (the online convertors don't seem to be able to do this):

```
private Action<AutoMappingExpressions> GetSetup()
{
    return c =>
    {
        c.FindIdentity = type => type.Name == "Id";
    };
}

private Action<IConventionFinder> GetConventions()
{
    return c =>
    {
        c.Add<MVCTemp.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.ForeignKeyConvention>();
        c.Add<MVCTemp.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.HasManyConvention>();
        c.Add<MVCTemp.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.HasManyToManyConvention>();
        c.Add<MVCTemp.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.ManyToManyTableNameConvention>();
        c.Add<MVCTemp.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.PrimaryKeyConvention>();
        c.Add<MVCTemp.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.ReferenceConvention>();
        c.Add<MVCTemp.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.TableNameConvention>();
    };
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: He's probably trying to convert it to VB.

Comment: Lambda with side effects ... is that a good thing?

Comment: @lpthnc: A lambda's just a means of declaring a delegate. The name of the delegate is `Action`, so I don't think it should come as any particular surprise (especially in light of the fact that there's no return value) that it "does something".

Comment: I believe multi line lambda expressions are coming in the next iteration of VB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you're trying to convert this to VB.Net.

Until Visual Basic 2010 (currently in [beta](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010/default.mspx)), it's not possible.

Lambda expressions in VB.Net 2008 can only hold a single expression.

However, you could create `Shared` helper functions that do the work and return them.

For example: (In VB)

```
Function GetConventions() As Action(Of IConventionFinder) 
    Return AddressOf GetConventionsHelper
End Function

Shared Sub GetConventionsHelper(c As IConventionFinder)
    c.Add(Of MVCTemp.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.ForeignKeyConvention)()
    c.Add(Of MVCTemp.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.HasManyConvention)()
    c.Add(Of MVCTemp.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.HasManyToManyConvention)()
    c.Add(Of MVCTemp.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.ManyToManyTableNameConvention)()
    c.Add(Of MVCTemp.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.PrimaryKeyConvention)()
    c.Add(Of MVCTemp.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.ReferenceConvention)()
    c.Add(Of MVCTemp.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.TableNameConvention)()
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the vague question yes I am trying to convert it to vb.net